# Joining tables NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, queryover

I would like to write following query to an NHibernate-QUery in order to get a list of PRESC_DEL ordered by PRESC.ADMINDATE

```
select * from PRESC_DEL, PRESC 
     where PRESC.ID = PRESC_DEL.ID_PRESC 
     and PRESC_DEL = PRESC_DEL.ID_DISTRIBUTIE
     or by PRESC.ADMINDATE
```

How do I make the join?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from pd in session.Query<PrescDel>()
             where pd.??? = pd.IdDistribute
             orderby pd.AdminDate
             select pd);

var results = query.Fetch(x => x.Presc).ToList();
```